# Excel ActiveX labels blink / change style upon clicking

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, activex

This, what seems to be a glitch, has annoyed me for years.  Some ActiveX controls, when placed on the worksheet, do odd things when clicked.  In the picture below, there is no code whatsoever and Label1 is disabled, but when Label1 is clicked, Label2 disappears.  I've also seen dark labels turn white upon clicking. The only way I know of to prevent this would be to use subclassing/hooking to intercept and cancel wm_mousedown messages when over the label but that is a ton of work for such a simple goal.  Does anybody out there have a simple solution for this?

*Edit: I believe what's happening is the z-order/z-index brings the clicked control to the top.  But if there's a way to prevent this I would love to know how.

[image: Label2 disappears when Label1 is clicked even though Label1 is disabled]

Here is an example of the background color changing when a label is clicked.  See the label with the caption "Original Value:"

[image: Some labels change background color when clicked]

Comment: You're saying that when you have physically overlapping labels, and you click the one that is behind, you want it to stay behind? The behavior you describe sounds by design. When you click something it changes the focus to the control, which normally you would want to be visible over anything that was placed over it.

Comment: Really? Normally to me things stay in the order they were originally designed.  The background image of a webpage doesn't cover the entire page when you click it, for example.  You don't want a panel to cover all the items on a panel when the panel is clicked.  The order shouldn't change based on clicks.  If it's by design, I think it's a stupid design

Comment: Apples and oranges. When you have two different browser windows open on top of each other, and you click one, it takes focus and covers the second window. You clicked it, so Windows assumes you want to see it over the other window. That is by design. Textboxes and command buttons do the same thing as labels.

Comment: Windows sure, but for controls like labels that's retarded

Answer (score -1):

Items should stay in the order they were laid out in, I have many projects with overlapping menus, shapes and labels and they all stay in the layer order they are organised in, the only time they move is if you programatically recreate them to update menues etc, then you need to write code to put them all back in order starting from the bottom up. If they are not staying in order then there is a problem and not a design flaw.